# Error when using initial_time_split with drake

Tags: tidymodels, drake-r-package

Learning how to use drake with tidymodels.

Something about using rsample's initial_time_split(), rather than just initial_split(), is giving me an error, when I run make(plan). I get the following:

```
#> > target data
#> > target split_data
#> Error in UseMethod("complement"): no applicable method for 'complement' applied to an object of class "rsplit"
```

Have really been racking my brain on this one. The function works fine, independently (ie. the following works):
[image]

I feel like I am missing something pretty basic.

Here is the full drake process in a single file (so that it is easier to post up on stack overflow).

Thanks in advance for the hints, as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
library(drake)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

###################################################################

generate_data <- function() {
  tibble(x = rnorm(1e5), y = rnorm(1e5))
}


split_the_data <- function(data) {
  
  data %>% 
    initial_time_split()
  
}


fit_model <- function(data) {
  
  summary(lm(y ~ x, data = data))
}



###################################################################


plan <- drake_plan(
  
  data = generate_data(),
  
  split_data = split_the_data(data),
  
  model = fit_model(training(split_data))
  
)


###################################################################


make(plan)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be fixed in the current development version (as of [93d60ef41119defc0432cc95d2dd6787e4a00b14](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commit/93d60ef41119defc0432cc95d2dd6787e4a00b14)). You can install it with

```r
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("ropensci/drake")
```

The error happened because `drake` calls `NROW()` on every target (for [dynamic branching](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/dynamic.html) purposes) and apparently `NROW()` errors on `rsplit` objects.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.2 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.2      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x scales::discard() masks purrr::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x recipes::fixed()  masks stringr::fixed()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x yardstick::spec() masks readr::spec()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()

generate_data <- function() {
    tibble(x = rnorm(1e5), y = rnorm(1e5))
}

split_the_data <- function(data) {
    data %>% 
        initial_time_split()
}

NROW(split_the_data(generate_data()))
#> Error in UseMethod("complement"): no applicable method for 'complement' applied to an object of class "rsplit"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Issue tracked in https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1300.